# Why does a semaphore that employs busy waiting cause a deadlock?

Tags: java, synchronization, deadlock, semaphore, wait

I have been playing around with implementing my own very basic semaphore and have noticed that the implementation I choose influences whether or not I get a deadlock. But I don't understand how the deadlock is happening.

My original implementation (no deadlock):

```
public synchronized void waitFor(){
    value--;
    if(value < 0)
    wait();
}

public synchronized void signal(){
    value++;
    notify();
}
```

A later implementation (results in deadlock):

```
public synchronized void waitFor(){
    value--;
    while(value < 0)
        wait();
}

public synchronized void signal(){
    value++;
    notifyAll();
}
```

The wait() is actually surrounded by a try-catch in both sets of code for catching thread interruptions, but I have left it out for readability and am assuming it makes no difference to the deadlock issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* program using the semaphore to demonstrate the problem. (We don't know whether you have enough threads signalling the semaphore, or what "this" is...)

Comment: I don't see how you can get a deadlock with only one lock... Note that in your first example you could miss a signal because you use `notify` and you could wake up too early because your wait is not within a loop.

Comment: what is the initial `value`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot any deadlock risk with the second implementation. The while loop is the right choice for waiting on a lock (See spurious wakeups in [Object.wait() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)).

Also, it looks like no signal operation can be missed. A signal can only occur when another thread is in a wait state, or when no other thread is running waitFor().

Therefore, I suggest that you check other parts of the code:

- Do all threads synchronize on the same instance of the semaphore?
- Are you sure that the value counter isn't used elsewhere, in a
  non-thread-safe manner?
- Do all threads call sepmaphore.signal() when
  they are done? (Typically this kind of release operations are placed in a finally block).

Answer (score 0):

This is because a synchronized method actually locks the whole object. So that if one synchronized method of an object is called, all other synchronized methods of the same object will wait.

As you stay in your waitFor method until value becomes less than 0 and your  signal method is waiting for the other sync method to complete, it deadlocked itself.

Try using getters and setters for your value and have them synchronize. That way only the actual access is synchronized and not the wait loop as well.

Answer (score -1):

as you are using

```
while(value < 0)
        wait();
```

in your latter implementation, it is within an non-ending loop for value <0 and it is looping here for ever.

This may be a pointer of your deadlock situation.

Comment: it is not looping foerever, only until some other thread calls `signal`.